# Detect keypress in console application?

Tags: c++, c, linux, keyboard, keypress

I need to detect a keypress in a console application, without prompting the user. Basically, my app is normally a daemon that listens to a special input device, but i need to simulate it on a dev box using the keyboard in interactive mode. How can I do this? - Im on a Linux system.

Comment: u know -- linux, keyboard input, curses

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing Keystrokes in GNU/Linux in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485116/capturing-keystrokes-in-gnu-linux-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't block while waiting for input, then you can use e.g. `select` to check if the `STDIN_FILENO` file descriptor is ready for reading, and if it is then you can use normal input functions (`scanf`, `fgets` `std::getline`, etc.).

Comment: Does this actually work?  In my testing (using the example from the select man page), select doesn't report that stdin is ready for reading until it sees a CR.

Comment: @JoeStrout You probably have to update the terminal flags as well, using [`tcsetattr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcsetattr.html).

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case on my test machines at least (one OS X, one Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

You check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1488272/610351) which explains how to read from the input events ( usually `/dev/input/event0`)

Or directly check the answer's source :

> Credits do not go to me, this code is taken from the Ventriloctrl hack to get keystrokes.
>   http://public.callutheran.edu/~abarker/ventriloctrl-0.4.tar.gz

Answer (score -3):

This text explaines hw to do such a thing. http://thc.org/papers/writing-linux-kernel-keylogger.txt