# How to capture key presses in linux two applications

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have two applications running on an embedded linux platform. I want to have the main application have focus with the keypad but I want another application in the background that can monitor key presses for the KEY_POWER to signal the system to shutdown.

We want to make this separate from the main app because turning the system off is important if the main app has crashed or hung.

[Capturing Keystrokes in GNU/Linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485116/capturing-keystrokes-in-gnu-linux-in-c) This doesn't seem to nicley if there are two apps reading from it. I think, i know evtest won't work with our main app up.

We do not have a window manager. Our only graphical app is Qt5, the other one is a background daemon.

Comment: You should add more details about your environment (running X? which window manager?). With X the right way to do this would be to have the window manager monitor KEY_POWER, but there are other more hacky ways...

Comment: added info to the question.